# SSL issue in Cloudfront with ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Loadbalancer with Amazon ACM. I have pointed A record to ELB in Route 53 ALand it works perfect with SSL and domain. But when I am pointing ELB to cloudfront getting SSL warning issue ..It would be great if someone help on this.

Comment: Is your CloudFront distribution setup to use a publicly recognised certificate? Or is it using a certificate from an internal/private authority or self-signed?

Comment: Also, what port is your ELB set to target on your CloudFront, 443?

Comment: oh..Actually I am not aware of this..can you guide me to set it public?

Comment: Ah okay, so did you issue your certificate via Amazon Certificate Manager for your? Review your cloudfront dist cert in Amazon Certificate manager, and check what value it says for "Type"

Comment: it says amazon issued

Comment: the certificate is public one

Comment: Okay, and if you review the Distribution settings for your CloudFront distrubution, for the 'SSL Certificate' value do you have 'Default cloudfront certificate' or do you have a custom ssl cert on. If the latter, does it match the cert you see in Amazon Certificate Manager?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219498/discussion-between-peter-reid-and-muneesh-duraipandi).

Comment: i am using custom certificate and selected the certificate issued by ACM

Answer (score 0):

When you have your domain in CloudFront you need to ensure you attach a valid SSL from ACM (within `us-east-1`) for the domain you'll be loading. In addition ensure you have added your domain under the additional domains property.

Without this you will be loading the CloudFront default SSL which is invalid for your host domain name.

More information about setting this up is available on the [Using Custom URLs for Files by Adding Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html) page.

Comment: Thankyou for answer. I am validating ACM in  us-east-1 only. I too added my www.domain.com in alertnate name in cloudfront and also added CNAME for www in Route53. I have also installed Letsencrypt in origin (EC2)  but when I hit cdn ednpoint it throws 502 error

Comment: If you help on this it will be never forgotten

Comment: Does it give you any feedback in the HTML of the response?

Comment: giving 502 error . request could not be sarisfied. cdn was not able to connect to origin

Comment: when i chose http only in origin protocol policy it works..but when i login to app it works with only http

Comment: Does your security group allow HTTPS access from the internet?

Comment: Are you able to connect to it in your browser (no SSL issues etc)?

Comment: yes..i am able to connect to my domain when i point to ELB and able to connect to secure connection..when i used cdn with http it too work...when i chose https only or match viewer it throws error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219610/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-muneesh-duraipandi).